# Adding a dynamic string to ContentArea macos_ui Flutter

Tags: flutter, macos

On a PushButton the action is to open a new MacosScaffold with a ContentArea like below.
On the **return** it now shows the **Center** widget

```
ContentArea(
  builder: (context, _) {
    return Center(
      child: PushButton(
        controlSize: ControlSize.regular,
          child: const Text('Go Back'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
              },
          ),
      );
  },
),
```

In a current project i'm working with dynamic strings to create pages.
On Android and Ios i'm able to use them like this:

```
onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pushNamed(
         context, Tab1Item1.routeTab1Items, arguments: index);
   },
```

Any idea on how I can use this on the "return" of the ContentArea?

I have not found any solution to create a dynamic route on the return in the ContentArea.
The only solution so far is actually build each page, but this takes away the advantage of dynamically created pages.